# Background, not update wallpaper and freezes

Tags: release-juno, wallpaper

After full-screen slack and roll up or close, last screen slack freeze on backgrond, but this is not freeze system work.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you are talking about wallpaper bug on gala?
Link: https://github.com/elementary/gala/issues/13